# Categorical variable in Rpy2 (factor function)

Tags: python, r, rpy2, logistic-regression

How can I do this in rpy2?
mydata is a dataframe and rank is a varaible from 1 to 4

```
mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/vector.html#dataframe, you have to do it in an indirect way:

```
In [51]:

import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as ro
import pandas.rpy.common as py2r
In [52]:

DF=pd.DataFrame({'val':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3]})
In [53]:

r_DF = py2r.convert_to_r_dataframe(DF)
In [54]:

print r_DF
  val
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   2
5   3
6   3

In [55]:

from rpy2.robjects.vectors import DataFrame
r_DF2=DataFrame({'factor': ro.r['factor'](r_DF.rx2('val')),
                 'val': r_DF.rx2('val')})
In [56]:

print r_DF2
  val factor
1   1      1
2   1      1
3   1      1
4   2      2
5   2      2
6   3      3
7   3      3
```